# Редирект не работает при наличии файла

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Сайт на `wordpess`.
Хочу при переходе на файл по прямой ссылке выдавать свою страницу, а не файл.

Код `htaccess`, размещен в самом верху файла.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*).zip$ ./download.php?link=$1
```

Работает, только если файл не существует; при наличии файла отдаёт его почему-то.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в конец [L] ``RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*).zip$ ./download.php?link=$1 [L]``

Comment: @YaMus не помогло(